# jdbc to HDFS import using spring batch job

Tags: spring, hdfs, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin, spring-xd

I am able to import data from my MS sql to HDFS using JDBCHDFC Spring Batch jobs.But if that containers fails , the job does not shift to other container. How do I proceed to make the job fault tolerant.
I am using spring xd 1.0.1 release

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which version of Spring XD you're currently using so I can't verify the exact behavior.  However, on a container failure with a batch job running in the current version, the job should be re-deployed to a new eligible container.  That being said, it will not restart the job automatically.  We are currently looking at options for how to allow a user to specify if they want it restarted (there are scenarios that fall into both camps so we need to allow a user to configure that).